# How can domain event inform the ui that price has changed?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have projects:

- ui
- application
- domain
- infrastructure

In the ui project I have a shopping cart in session:

```
public class Cart
{
    public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; } = new List<CartItem>();
}

public class CartItem
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

In the domain project I throw the event **ProductPriceHasChangedEvent**. In application project I have the event handler: **ProductPriceHasChangedEventHandler** - how can I refresh the product price in shopping carts in user sessions? The project application doesn't have the reference to the project ui and doesn't have the reference to httpcontext and session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI (user's shopping cart with active open session) has to query your application for latest prices of the cart's items.

The best way I think would be to periodically reload your cart, performing all the logic that initial load does. Then you've got all the information in cart refreshed, not only prices, ie descriptions, item availability (if needed) etc.

Assuming we are talking about single page JS app + Web API:

make you cart's JavaScript to query API to reload cart every say, hour (the time period is up to you):

`GET /api/users/<userid>/cart`

And refresh your UI from the incoming data. This way you'll stay updated with the latest prices.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is past the purview of DDD. DDD doesn't directly deal with communication between the UI and the domain, nor does it make recommendations based on it. In fact, DDD is very clear in being UI-agnostic. To solve your problem though: There are two main ways you can update a UI:

1. Pull (polling) - Like @Alex-Buyny describes, you'll make periodic calls to the server to get the latest information and update your UI based on the results. The cleanest way to do this is through a single page app and an REST API backend. You could ofcourse just cause a reload at intervals too.
2. Server Push - The server pushes to your UI when there's an update available. This method relies on websockets and is quite a bit more complex than polling. It's also more efficient with it's use of resources and is generally demands a much more robust solution.

Comment: Thx man !! Thx You both.. I will periodically reload my cart.